# Getting incorrect number of paramaters in callback error using Moq

Tags: c#, moq, extension-methods

I'm getting the following error when trying to fake a db set as a list using Moq:

> System.ArgumentException   HResult=0x80070057   Message=Invalid
>   callback. Setup on method with 0 parameter(s) cannot invoke callback
>   with different number of parameters (1).   Source=Moq   StackTrace:
>   at Moq.MethodCallReturn 2.ValidateReturnDelegate(Delegate callback)
>   at Moq.MethodCallReturn 2.Returns(Func`1 valueExpression)    at

Here's my code.  It should be relatively simple.

```
var mockContext = new Mock<IContext>();
var lhList = new List<LogicHistory>();
mockContext.Setup(x => x.Set<LogicHistory>()).Returns(lhList.AsDbSet);
```

Here's my extension method.

```
public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList) where T : class
{
    var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
    var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
    mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
    mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(sourceList.Add);
    mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns<T>(x => { if (sourceList.Remove(x)) return x; else return null; });

    return mockDbSet.Object;
}
```

I used this exact same method a year ago and it worked perfectly.  I'm looking at my old unit tests and they run fine.  Then I try running this, and it doesn't work.  It looks functionally identical to me.  The only differences are the variable names.  The Set method is identical in both context interfaces:

```
DbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
```

Anyone have any thoughts on what the problem is?

Comment: You are calling the extension method incorrectly `.Returns(lhList.AsDbSet());`. Note you are missing the brackets `()` after extension name

Comment: Or `.Returns(() => lhList.AsDbSet())`  if you want to use lambda syntax. Missing out the parens means the function take a parameter, which in this case is not true.

Comment: Ok...that works.  I wonder why my old unit tests work just fine without the parens.

Comment: Older version of Moq? Are you 100% sure the old ones were also missing the parens?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking at them right now.  They work just fine.  It is a slightly older build of Moq.

Comment: just for information, we've been using [FakeDbSet](https://gist.github.com/LukeWinikates/1309447) for a couple of years now, very easy to implement and works very well.